# Translation file [.......] contains an invalid JSON structure

Tags: json, traducción

Tengo un archivo de traducciones para las notificaciones de correo electrónico, dentro de `resources/lang`, al que he llamado `es.json`. Su listado es el siguiente:

```
{
    "Verify Your Email Address" : "Verifique su dirección de e-mail",
    "Please click the button below to verify your email address." : "Pulse el botón que aparece a continuación para verificar su correo.",
    "Verify Email Address" : "Verificar correo electrónico",
    "If you did not create an account, no further action is required." : "Si usted no ha creado una cuenta, puede borrar este correo sin más.",
    "Reset Password Notification" : "Restablecimiento de contraseña",
    "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account." : "Ha recibido este correo porque ha solicitado restablececer la contraseña de su cuenta.", 
    "Reset Password" : "Restablecer contraseña",
    "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes." : "Este enlace expirará en :count minutos.", 
    "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required." : "Si no solicitó el restablecimiento de su contraseña, simplemente ignore este correo.", 
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)" : "Si tiene problemas usando el botón \":actionText\", copie y pegue la siguiente dirección en su navegador: [:actionURL](:actionURL)",
}
```

Cuando intento acceder al registro de usuarios, me salta una excepción, así:

```
Translation file [C:\laragon\www\prueba\resources\lang/es.json] contains an invalid JSON structure. (View: C:\laragon\www\prueba\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)
```

El archivo está correctamente formateado en JSON, como se puede ver arriba. Además, la vista `register.blade.php` ni siquiera hace uso de ese archivo. En su lugar, emplea un archivo de traducción PHP en la ruta `resources/lang/auth.register.php`, que aparece a continuación:

```
<?php
    return [
        // Vista del formulario de registro
        'Register' => 'Registro',
        'First Name' => 'Nombre',
        'Surname' => 'Apellido(s)',
        'Username' => 'Nombre de usuario',
        'E-Mail Address' => 'Dirección de e-mail',
        'Password' => 'Contraseña',
        'Confirm Password' => 'Confirme contraseña',

        // Vista de verificación de email
        'Verify Your Email Address' => 'Verifique su dirección de e-mail',
        'A fresh verification link has been sent to your email address.' => 'Se ha enviado un nuevo enlace de veridficación a su dirección de email.',
        'Before proceeding, please check your email for a verification link.' => 'Antes de continuar, por favor, busque en el correo el enlace de verificación',
        'If you did not receive the email' => 'Si no ha racibido el e-mail',
        'click here to request another' => 'pulse aquí para que le enviemos otro',
    ];
```

Resumiendo. El archivo JSON es sólo para las notificaciones de correo electrónico. ¿Por qué se me produce esta excepción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que tu string json no debe de tener ninguna coma `,` en el último elemento.

Cambia esto

```
{
    "Verify Your Email Address" : "Verifique su dirección de e-mail",
    "Please click the button below to verify your email address." : "Pulse el botón que aparece a continuación para verificar su correo.",
    "Verify Email Address" : "Verificar correo electrónico",
    "If you did not create an account, no further action is required." : "Si usted no ha creado una cuenta, puede borrar este correo sin más.",
    "Reset Password Notification" : "Restablecimiento de contraseña",
    "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account." : "Ha recibido este correo porque ha solicitado restablececer la contraseña de su cuenta.", 
    "Reset Password" : "Restablecer contraseña",
    "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes." : "Este enlace expirará en :count minutos.", 
    "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required." : "Si no solicitó el restablecimiento de su contraseña, simplemente ignore este correo.", 
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)" : "Si tiene problemas usando el botón \":actionText\", copie y pegue la siguiente dirección en su navegador: [:actionURL](:actionURL)",
}
```

A esto:

```
{
    "Verify Your Email Address" : "Verifique su dirección de e-mail",
    "Please click the button below to verify your email address." : "Pulse el botón que aparece a continuación para verificar su correo.",
    "Verify Email Address" : "Verificar correo electrónico",
    "If you did not create an account, no further action is required." : "Si usted no ha creado una cuenta, puede borrar este correo sin más.",
    "Reset Password Notification" : "Restablecimiento de contraseña",
    "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account." : "Ha recibido este correo porque ha solicitado restablececer la contraseña de su cuenta.", 
    "Reset Password" : "Restablecer contraseña",
    "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes." : "Este enlace expirará en :count minutos.", 
    "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required." : "Si no solicitó el restablecimiento de su contraseña, simplemente ignore este correo.", 
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)" : "Si tiene problemas usando el botón \":actionText\", copie y pegue la siguiente dirección en su navegador: [:actionURL](:actionURL)"
}
```

Comment: Guau, gracias, @Fernando Torres.